# Standard or boost algorithm for finding the index for the minimum of f(Xi)

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost

My problem is following:
Given a contaner X = {x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ...,x<sub>n</sub>} and a function `f`, find the index `i` where the value f(x<sub>i</sub>) reaches the minimum.

Of course, I can implement it from scratch, but I've got a feeling that I've invented a bicycle, so I'm looking for a shorter code using standard or boost algorithms. The best I could get was

```
template <typename Val>
Val f(Val)
{
.........
}

template <typename It>
It find_minimum(It begin, It end)
{
return std::min_element(begin, end, 
   [](typename It::value_type val1, typename It::value_type val2)
  {
  return f(val1) < f(val2);
  });
}
```

but it suffers from the problem that `f` is evaluated 2N-1 times.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this algorithm (pseudo code, don't have time to make it template correct)

```
It element= X.first()
Val min = f(element)
It min_el = element
while(element= element.next())
{
    Val temp = f(element);
    if( min > temp)
    {
        min_el = element;
        min = temp;
    }
}
return min_el
```

Comment: I wonder if there is an algorithm I can call instead of coding it myself from scratch

Comment: If there's not such algorithm you write it once with templates, and you got it forever ;). This algorithm evaluates F only once for each element, and is applicable also for long input streams, element is copied only if "min>temp", the longest the "while" runs, lesser the chance to copy an element, so also in case "temp = f(element)" is expensive its cost will be reduced on longest run (unless input is sorted, but then other algorithms fits better)

Comment: That is what I'm doing, but I've got a feeling that I've invented a bicycle

Comment: Wouldn't expect being able to simplify the loop. I'd just use a `for(auto &x : X)`, if available, but other than that...

Answer (score 0):

How about using an additional step to calculate and store all `f(x)`, then look for the minimum value?

Alternative idea: Iterate over all possible values of x and store the previous minimum only?

Comment: It allocates extra memory. In addition, if `min_element` were used for finding the minimum, it would return an iterator for that temporary storage

Comment: @Andrey if extra memory is a constraint, maybe you should specify it in the question.

Comment: Don't think you can solve this without any additional memory usage. It's processing time vs. memory usage in the end I guess.

Comment: Actually, the only other solution I could come up with would be a numerical solution deriving `f()`, although that might get tricky.

Comment: @Mario: This is more a limitation of how `min_element` works, not a fundamental limit...

Comment: there's no guarantee that the function is monotonic or change derivate with low frequency. There's no guarantee that X is sorted. The only way is process F(x) once for every X

Comment: True, but it would also depend on how or what `f()` returns. It could be in proportional to x, but it could also depend on previous results.

Comment: @Mario: If `f` is stateful, then all bets are off; the result would depend on the iteration order!

Comment: @Mario let's assume that `f` is a function in the mathematical sense. Otherwise it would be difficult to determine a minimum for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use lambda with state, if you *do* know implementataion of std::min_element

```
auto minElt = std::min_element(data.begin(), data.end(), [f](const int& a, const int& b)->bool
                               {
                                   static int minValCash = f(b);
                                   int v2 = f(a);
                                   bool result = v2 < minValCash;
                                   if(!result)
                                    std::swap(v2, minValCash);
                                   return result;
                               });
```

Comment: why not putting state in an object rather than a static variable?

Comment: static variable is simply shorter and allows to avoid additional check of data to be empty, but you are totally right, putting an additional variable as a state of the lambda works too.

Comment: Doesn't the static variable mean that you can only do this once?

Answer (score 0):

The shorter answer I can find uses std::min_element and boost::transform_iterator:

```
return std::min_element(
  boost::make_transform_iterator(begin, f), 
  boost::make_transform_iterator(end, f)).base();
```

However, it may need 2N-1 function calls depending on the std::min_element implementation.